# Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection eating all available ram before crashing

Tags: windows-10, memory, event-log, windows-defender

For couple of days now I've been experiancing issues, where Windows Defender ATP process just starts to grab all my RAM, reaching up to 40GB of 48 available and then crashing. I've noticed a lot of "SenseNdrPktmon" has reached its maximum size warnings in Event viewer, and obviously, I can't increse size of log as it's restricted in service components. After crashing in Event viewer, there are also following errors:

> The Windows Defender Advanced Threat Protection Service service
> terminated unexpectedly. It has done this 14 time(s). The following
> corrective action will be taken in 300000 milliseconds: Restart the
> service.

> Session "SenseIRTraceLogger" failed to start with the following error:
> 0xC0000035

> Session "SenseNdrPktmon" failed to start with the following error:
> 0xC0000035

> Session "SenseEventLog" failed to start with the following error:
> 0xC0000035

> The Windows Error Reporting Service service terminated with the
> following error:

> The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.

> A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the
> Windows Error Reporting Service service to connect.

> Windows successfully diagnosed a low virtual memory condition. The
> following programs consumed the most virtual memory: MsSense.exe
> (27532) consumed 91168595968 bytes

> The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
> {C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
> and APPID
> {316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
> to the user XX-XX\X SID (X) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.19041.1320_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy SID (x). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: (A) Is the paging file set to Automatic?  (B) Open Windows Defender and then in About (lower left) (1) update Defender manually and (2) make sure Antimalware is up to date.

Comment: @John (A) - yes, paging is set to Automatic for all drives, (B) unless we're thinking of different things, it's up to date (Windows Security -> Virus & threat protection)