# Session "SenseNdrPktmon" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035

Tags: windows

This one has me stumped.
Brand new windows 10 Laptop continuously drops from the network. like 50 times a day and reconnects 3-4 seconds after.

This happens regardless of network or network type, tried LAN, Wifi and Mobile hotspots. Also tried in different networks. No other device in the current network has the same issue.

Updated all the drivers,
Reset the network adapters,
Reimaged the device twice,
Got the motherboard replaced and started from a fresh install from the manufacturer's site(LENOVO)
Every time the network disconnects event viewer logs in this error multiple times:

**Session "SenseNdrPktmon" failed to start with the following error: 0xC0000035**

I don't have a clue what to do next, any advice is appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Brand new windows 10 Laptop continuously drops from the network.  ... Have you asked the Manufacturer?  Possible hardware error.

Comment: Yes, they replaced the motherboard today and after installing the OS again issue persists. everything is integrated other than the hard drive.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge and experience, this is not a Windows (or Mac or Linux) issue.   Perhaps escalate with the manufacturer since you reinstalled the OS.

Comment: Could be a hard drive problem, maybe one bit flipped right where the network driver sits? If the same image gets deployed again, it'll end up on exactly the same physical location and rinse, repeat.

Comment: This is evidently hardware. If you have replaced the motherboard but the problem is elsewhere, why don't you go the whole route and get the entire computer replaced?

Answer (score 0):

You have done everything possible with software and the problem remaims.
This is evidently a hardware problem.

The vendor has replaced the motherboard, but the problem remains.
The problem must be elsewhere, but replacing all the parts one by one
until the problem is gone is a waste of time.

As this is a new computer, still under warranty, I suggest
to go the whole route and to ask to have the entire computer replaced.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try disabling Windows Firewall & possibly Defender. [Google tells](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/732238/since-sunday-02062022-sensendrpktmon-maximum-size.html) [me that error](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/sensendrpktmon-causing-windows-to-lock-up/928a292c-a1f5-4b80-898e-388c9e0a9c8d?auth=1) [seems to be relating to a Defender](https://superuser.com/questions/1685748/windows-defender-advanced-threat-protection-eating-all-available-ram-before-cras) monitoring process. Maybe a bad Windows update caused it to wig out & take down the network its monitoring OR its gobbling/leaking all the RAM causing the network driver to fail?
2. On that topic RAM causes weird issues sometimes, I'd test that (memtest86 or a diagnostic that may be built-into Lenovo).
3. [Try Safe](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234) [Mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/advanced-startup-options-including-safe-mode-b90e7808-80b5-a291-d4b8-1a1af602b617) or [Clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows-da2f9573-6eec-00ad-2f8a-a97a1807f3dd), does issue happen there?
4. I want to be 100% sure you said this is happening on wired Ethernet (LAN as you say) as well as Wi-Fi with at least two networks?